# How to combine multiple trendlines in a single chart?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm new in here and I love the forum already! I'm stuck with a problem now. I am doing financial ratio analysis of a company for five years and I need to show the ratios in a trendline. I have generated separate line charts for each ratio, but I want to combine the charts and have multiple trendlines for multiple data series in a chart. Is this possible? Any help is much appreciated.

I'm not really proficient in excel, so please explain your answer fully. I know I am asking for a lot, but I am really desperate for a solution. This is driving me crazy!!

a scrrenshot of the table i want the trendlines for 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is more for one trendline but with multiple series, what I would do is:

- Make a series of all needed values per row added together.
- Then divide by how many there are (2, divide by 2, 3, divide by 3, etc.).
- Next, make a graph like usual with all needed series including the one you just made.
- Then create a trendline **only** for the one you just made.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to get a chart that you describe.  First, the easiest:

1. Select your data (in this case Quick Ratio, Cash Ratio and Net Working Capital and all of their data points).
2. Insert a line chart.
3. Select your first data series and add a trendline.
4. Re-select the first data series and reformat the line to No Line.
5. Repeat this for each data series and trendline combination.
6. Once complete your chart will have 3 series hidden (by No Line formatting) and 3 Trendlines that need to be formatted and labeled.
7. Format to taste.

The obvious problem with this method is that you'll have twice as many series as necessary on the chart, and this can be a nuisance for long term maintenance and performance.

The second, better, option is to create an additional series for each set of values and use the =TREND Excel function (be careful, this is an Array Function), and then chart those values directly.  This will limit the number of data series on your chart and you won't have any hidden series to deal with.

Comment: You only need one series, because you can get multiple trendlines from a single series. Right click the series, choose Add Trendline, format the trendline. Again, right click the series, choose Add Trendline, format the trendline. Rinse and repeat.